# Voice chat in Google Drive

Tags: google-drive

I was working collaboratively with a Google Drive document at the same time i was speaking to the other parties on Skype voice chat.

It got me thinking is there a voice chat feature inbuilt into Google Drive ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, but it works the other way around. You can start a Hangout and work on a document from there.

See [The Next Web: Google+ is becoming a beast for the workplace, Google Docs now available in Hangouts](http://thenextweb.com/socialmedia/2012/03/13/google-is-becoming-a-beast-for-the-workplace-google-docs-now-available-in-hangouts/) and [Sharing Documents on Hangout with extras](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1C5G2_sLALP_CgT0YriW1X70qI3YQ3aq10DMNB58xPTs/edit) for details.